# Как работает Group By аггрегатная функция и Having во вложенном запросе?

Tags: mysql

Не понимаю почему вложенный запрос возвращает 4 строки, когда по логике  должен был вернуть 3. Есть таблица с товарами, ключевые поля цена и категория.

Если выделить внутренний запрос и выполнить самостоятельно, вернется ожидаемо 3 строки - запрашивается данные из таблицы , они (1) сгруппированны и (2) отфильтрованны хавнгом.
Вот внутренни запрос:

```
SELECT max(`buyPrice`) `max_bp` 
from `products`
GROUP BY `category` HAVING `max_bp` > 999
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тепрь полный запрос, у которого внутри тот, что выше:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products`
WHERE `buyPrice` IN (
    SELECT max(`buyPrice`) `max_bp` 
    from `products` AS `p`
    WHERE `products`.`buyPrice` = `p`.`buyPrice`
    GROUP BY `category` HAVING `max_bp` > 999
)
```

И вот это вложенный вернет почему-то 4 строки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такое впечатление, что внутренний GROUP BY перестает работать. Ведь **WHERE `buyPrice` IN** получив 3 строки должен бы просто расширить таблицу.
Не прошу исправить его, а лишь пояснить как это работает?

Вся таблица и запросы тут [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f8dd5/2)

Comment: [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: А зачем тут `WHERE products.buyPrice = p.buyPrice` он делает подзапрос корелированнм и он выполняется не 1 раз, а для каждой строки products и при этом делает выборку максимальной строки из строк, которые равны той для которой сейчас идет выборка. По идее он вам вернет вообще все строки > 999

Comment: И если задача "найти группы товаров", то почему вы выбираете сами товары ?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/zF9oYTq1 - запрос выводит все **товары** с ценой более 999.

Comment: @Mike вот почему все строки > 999 а не три как внутренний?

Comment: @Mike, ок понятно, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А может быть вот так тогда:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `products`,
(
    SELECT max(`buyPrice`) `max_bp`, `category` 
    from `products` AS `p`
    GROUP BY `category` HAVING `max_bp` > 999
) `m`
WHERE `products`.`buyPrice` = `m`.`max_bp` AND
      `products`.`category` = `m`.`category`
```

А почему возвращает 4 строки вам объяснили в комментарии. Фактически в вашем запросе группировка происходит с учётом `WHERE`, то есть группируются между собой только записи с той же `buyPrice`, что и в каждой строке основной таблицы. Таким образом, максимум по категории на самом деле не ищется из-за `WHERE` в запросе с группировкой. Максимум в этом случае оказывается равен цене каждого конкретного товара в `products`.

Comment: Это решение, да.  Но я еще просил объяснить почему же внутренний запрос вернет 3 строки а внешний уже 4

Comment: @valera Попробовал разъяснить, хотя во втором комментарии к вопросу это уже объяснено.